# Which method is better to toggle Class onClick with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've often seen 2 methods to add or toggle a class using javascript:

```
var $mainmenu = $('.navigation'),
$menuToggle = $('.trigger');

$menuToggle.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $mainmenu.toggleClass('active');
});
```

and what looks like a much simpler way:

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.navigation').toggleClass("active");
});
```

Which method would you say is better and why?

Comment: If you are using same selector in multiple place then first way is better, otherwise you can just go with second one. But always I prefer the first one ;)

Comment: It depends on the scenario. If the elements that can be matched by `$('.navigation')` aren't expected to change (added, removed, replaced), the 1st will benefit from saving the result rather than repeatedly researching. However, if the elements are expected to change, the 1st will not reflect those changes -- the selector should be used again to find elements currently within the page at the time of the `'click'` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method you are creating

- one semi-local scoped variable $mainmenu
- one global variable $menuToggle

This is not a good practice if you only want to use the variables inside the click callback, so I would use the second

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.navigation').toggleClass("active");
});
```

Note: If you add a variable here using var, it will only live inside the callback function

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
    var $nav = $('.navigation')
    $nav.toggleClass("active");
});
```

Also in the first one you use `event.preventDefault();` this will stop the default action, you can read about it here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is good for when you need to call the same DOM element multiple times - querying the DOM is an expensive process, so if you need to grab something from it that will be used multiple times, do it once and store it in a variable.

The second example is good if you only need to complete this function once. It saves lines of code and is more human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second.  It looks cleaner and doesn't leave a lot of room to misinterpret. It is *slightly* slower in clock cycles to have it retrieve the navigation item per click, but unless your user is literally clicking thousands of times per second, those few clock cycles aren't going to be noticeable at all.